# WebGL was lost context | Selenium Python

Tags: python, windows, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to enter the site kad.arbitr.ru through using selenium on python via geckodriver (Firefox). But when I enter the site it shows me the following error in the console:

```
JavaScript warning: https://kad.arbitr.ru/ line 1 > injectedScript, line 1: WebGL context was lost.
```

Also I got the same problem using other drivers, like chrome or opera
How can I fix it?

Thank you for help!

Comment: can you try with --- option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--disable-webgl")

Comment: Unfortunately it didn’t help